# Macbook Pro (Late 2010) slow after installing Mavericks

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, performance

I've recently updated my 15-inch, Mid 2010 Macbook Pro to Mavericks. Since then, it's been running incredibly slow and tends to hang while using programs such as FireFox or Excel.

If I look at the activity monitor, the only task taking up a large amount of resources is `kernal_task`.

I've verified the hard drive through disk utility, and it said that the drive is fine. Here's the hardware overview, if that helps:

> **Hardware Overview:**
>
> Model Name: MacBook Pro
>
> Model Identifier:   MacBookPro6,2
>
> Processor Name: Intel Core i5
>
> Processor Speed:    2.53 GHz
>
> Number of Processors:   1
>
> Total Number of Cores:  2
>
> L2 Cache (per Core):    256 KB
>
> L3 Cache:   3 MB
>
> Memory: 4 GB
>
> Processor Interconnect Speed:   4.8 GT/s
>
> Boot ROM Version:   MBP61.0057.B0C

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: Do you have any kind of Virus scanner ruining? What does it show as Memory load in Activity.

Comment: No virus scanner. Memory load is at full, though the only large task is the kernal.

Comment: Did you do a clean install of Mavericks? How much free disk space do you have? In the Activity Monitor, which process(es) are using more CPU time?

Comment: Maybe its the spotlight indexing? Check this by click on the spotlight icon in the upper right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mathias711 pointed out in the comments, the cause of this was Spotlight automatically re-indexing after the after the OS upgrade. The process of indexing was greatly slowed down by OSX attempting to index a very slow, old external drive we had hooked up.

Once the indexing had finished (it actually took quite a while) the laptop eventually returned to its former speed.

There's also [a post by Computer World](http://www.computerworld.com/article/2475254/mac-os-x/how-to-improve-mac-performance--os-x-mavericks-edition.html) that backs up this conclusion:

> OS X will rebuild the Spotlight index after a major System upgrade. The process takes time and degrades performance while it takes place.
>
> Click on the Spotlight (looking glass) icon to the top right of the display to see if indexing is taking place. If indexing is in progress you should see a dot in the middle of the looking glass icon and/or be told the operation is taking place. Allow the process to complete and you should see immediate performance improvement.